# Removing and reformatting of NSDate is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to reformat this NSdate (2016-02-11 01:00:00 +0000 ) into this (11-02-2016).

I have used below code and its returning null.

```
//newDate format is 2016-02-11 01:00:00 +0000
NSString *dateString = [[self dateFormatter] stringFromDate:newDate];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

// Convert date object into desired format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"people%@",newDateString); //printing null
```

Comment: create a new date formatter and try.

Comment: Dates are in UTC. They have no time zone. What you are trying to do, modifying an NSDate, is totally misguided and wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`+0000` it the time zone definition. You should parse it with `Z`

try this

```
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
```

else if your date is current date use

```
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: if it is not work can you show more code before this line newDate what you written

Comment: why assign the negative Vote, if I made the Mistake I surely modify my answer

Comment: newDate is obviously an NSDate. You cannot parse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myString = @"2016-02-11 11:29:04";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way

```
NSString *strDateFor = @"2016-02-11 01:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateformate dateFromString:strDateFor];
NSLog(@"date : %@",date);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"The strDate is - %@", strDate);
```

The Console output is

```
date : 2016-02-11 01:00:00 +0000
The strDate is - 11-02-2016
```